# Pullback Formula for Top-Degree Form in terms of Arbitrary Frames

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I'm wondering if the nice pullback formula for top-degree forms (Prop. 14.20 from Lee's Intro. to Smooth manifolds) [image: Lee, Prop.14.20]

holds more generally for frame fields and not just coordinate fields. What I mean is suppose $F : M \rightarrow N$, and let $Z_1, \cdots, Z_n$ be a frame on $U\subset M$ and $Z_1^*, \cdots, Z_n^*$ the corresponding dual frame. Similarly, let $W_1, \cdots, W_n$ be a frame on $V\subset N$ and $W_1^*, \cdots, W_n^*$ the corresponding dual frame.

Since $DF$ is just the map that takes the tangent space at each point $p$ in $U$ to the corresponding tangent space at $F(p)$ in $V$, we can write this map in terms of the the $Z_1, \cdots, Z_n$ and $W_1, \cdots, W_n$ bases. Call this map $DF_{ZW}$. Then it seems like the following should hold (ignoring the function $u$ for the moment):
$$
F^* (W_1^* \wedge \cdots \wedge W_n^*) = (\det DF_{ZW} ) Z_1^* \wedge \cdots \wedge Z_n^*.
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I wouldn't write this as $DF_{ZW}$, but at a single point if $A$ is the matrix giving the change of basis from $Z$ to $W$, then $\det A$ is the correct factor. This is just linear algebra (as was the coordinate-change case).

Comment: More broadly, the top-degree form composed of frame 1-forms should be proportional to the top-degree form composed of coordinate 1-forms by some non-zero function.